# problemas de comparacion de datos en spring boot con jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Hola tengo un problema estoy trabajando con spring boot y jpa tengo este codigo donde horarios_bd son todos los horarios que saco de la base de datos y le envio como parametro otro horario que yo ingrese por formulario entonces la cosa es que cuando yo quiero comparar dos campos de un horario de la lista que saco de la base de datos con el horario que ingreso me sale que no son iguales por ejemplo en el codigo horario.getAula() me da el aula de ese horario y hora.getAula() me da el aula del primer registro de la base de datos segun los logs que puse alli los dos escriben laboratorios entonces son iguales pero al momento de compararlos dentro de ese if me dice que son diferentes y salta al else este es mi problema porque deberia de entrar en el if ya que son iguales.

```
public boolean validar_ingreso(Horarios horario) {



    List<Horarios> horarios_bd = sacar_horarios();

    boolean validar = false;
    String aula1,aula2;

    if(horarios_bd.isEmpty()) {
        validar = true;
    }
    else {
        for(Horarios hora : horarios_bd) {

            logger.info("horario ->"+horario.getAula());
            logger.info("hora ->"+hora.getAula());

            aula1 = horario.getAula();
            aula2 = hora.getAula();
            if(aula2==aula1){
                validar = false;
                break;
            }
            else {
                validar = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return validar;


}
```

Pongo los logs que me salen como ven me salen los dos iguales pero no entra en ese if ya busque e intente varias cosas pero nada funciona espero que me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0):

En Java solamente se deben comparar con == los tipos primitivos ( `int`, `long`, etc ), los objetos tienes que compararlos con el metodo `equals`.

Comment: Gracias si salia con eso no me acordaba de ese metodo.

Answer (score 0):

para la comparación de String se debe usar equals, donde se compara la constante antes de la variable, para no incurrir en un nullPointerException, si lo haces de la siguiente manera te funciona perfecto saludos,

puedes usar iqualsIngnoreCase en caso que aul pueda esta en mayúsculas o minúsculas.+}

supongo que aula es de tipo String ya que no lo mencionas.

```
 if(horario.getAula().equals(hora.getAula())){
        System.out.println(" true");
    }
```

no es necesario crear variables de mas, ya que los valores están dentro de los objetos, con esto solo ocupas memoria,
por eso se llama programacion orientada a objetos.